# Integral containing inverse $\tanh$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I solve this integral containing inverse $\tanh$? Does it have any antiderivative?
$$
\int \cfrac{t^2}{\sqrt{r^2-t^2}} \cdot \operatorname{arctanh}\sqrt{1-t^2}\; \mathrm{dt}
$$

Comment: use $$arctanh (x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln (\frac{1+x}{1-x})$$ and integrate by parts with $\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{r^2-t^2}}$as the integrating part and $\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-t^2}})$ the differentating part

Comment: Its expression will contain [polylogarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). Also, use the fact that $\ln\dfrac ab=\ln a-\ln b$, and $\ln a^b=b\ln a$.